# Why this local variable is not available?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Recently I stumbled upon this during a debugging session in IntelliJ IDEA(CommunityEdition build#IC182.3684.101). 
[image: goes through a catch]

So, even when debugger is inside a catch block, it does not have access to local variable and so no operation (peek, evaluate) can be performed on them. Sometimes it is irritating because we will have to let it throw the exception and stop current execution for it.

Shouldn't these local variables be available till block has finished execution?
or Is it only in IntelliJ IDEA ?

Comment: Please post code and markup and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 (You can *also* include a picture if it helps by showing the problem in context.)

Comment: It should have access.  Are you sure you're actually inside the catch block and not on the catch line?

Comment: Unless @SteveSmith is right, my guess is that you've built the project without optimizations turned off and the variable has been optimized away.

Comment: I have included a screenshot because it was not a single instance, but there were multiple instances of it

Comment: Or perhaps the code running in the debugger is out of synch with the editor for some other reason. I don't have much experience in IDEA, but in eclipse I would try a "refresh" of the project.

Comment: @SteveSmith, yes, You can see in the screenshot, the blue line highlights the line currently being executed and it is in catch block

Comment: Use Eclipse. ;) Or does this help: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206154629-Cannot-find-local-variable-only-for-some-parameters

Comment: @Steve, no, I think it is specific to catch block, afaik

Comment: I dont think I have set debugging with optimizations turned on  @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: What local variables are available at that point? Debugger may be wrong for variables naming in decompiled code.

Comment: I agree with @Hulk - most times I've had IntelliJ debugger weirdness it was due to the project being out of date with the code - maybe there were build errors, maybe you have another running copy of the code (in the IDE) which is preventing a rebuild, etc.

Comment: @dan.m, as I mentioned, it happened at multiple instances, not only once where we might have made mistake, out of sync code.

Comment: @KumarAnkit - *"I have included a screenshot because it was not a single instance..."* Doesn't matter. Include the **text** of the example you've provided as a screenshot.